# why is there no setStyle for WebGLPointsLayer

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I am using the `WebGLPointsLayer` as shown in [this official OL workshop tutorial](https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/webgl/points.html). I am now trying to deviate a little from the code supplied there and figure out a way to change the layer's style in response to user actions. I am looking for a `setStyle` method like the one that exists on the [VectorLayer](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html) but none can be found. Incidentally I also note that the `WebGLPointsLayer` class is undocumented as of v6.4.3: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/

So the question is: how do I change the style on a `WebGLPointsLayer` and where is the API documented?

The only workaround I have discovered is to create the layer from scratch and use `map.getLayers().setAt(index, layer)` to replace it on the map.

Comment: It is not shown in the documentation as it is still "experimental" but like all of OpenLayers the source code uses jsdoc and is self-documenting https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/layer/WebGLPoints.js

Answer (score 0):

You're right; there is no way to change the style of an existing WebGL layer. It uses a totally different renderer to regular vector layers.

There is now an official example of changing the style of an existing WebGL layer here: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/webgl-points-layer.html. They use a very similar method to the one you use in your question.